# Show that $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{kx^2 + n}$ converges pointwise to $\ln(1+x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I show that the functions $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{kx^2+n}$ converges pointwise to $\ln(1+x^2)~$?

The confusing part is that both $k$ and $n$ is in the denominator. I am new at this and don't seem to understand exactly how to treat their asymptotic behavior

First, I just tried to integrate directly:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{kx^2+n}~dn$$but this diverges to $\infty$

Then I divided the numerator and denominator with $x^2$ and tried to use asymptotics when comparing the sum with an integral

Is it correct to say that $\frac{1}{k+\frac{n}{x^2}}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{n/x^2} = \frac{x^2}{n}$ as $k$ vanishes when $n$ grows arbitrarily large?. But even so, trying to integrate that last part I just end up with divergent integrals no matter how I try to manipulate the original expression.
I havent taken any courses dealing with these subjects so I'm starting to think I'm going about this completely wrong.

How does $f_n(x)$ converge to $\ln(1+x^2)~$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the sequence of functions that you have, as written, is not defined because for every finite $n$ and $x\neq 0$, the series diverges by comparison test with the harmonic series. Most likely the actual problem is supposed to be:

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2}{kx^2+n}$$

Now rewrite the summation as follows

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2}{kx^2+n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2}{x^2\frac{k}{n}+1}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Notice that this is a Riemann sum, which in the limit we can rewrite as an integral.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2}{x^2\frac{k}{n}+1}\cdot \frac{1}{n} = \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{x^2t + 1}\:dt = \log(x^2t+1)\Bigr|_0^1 = \log(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Yes, the upper bond of the sum if $n$, not $\infty$. I just wonder why you integrated from 0 to 1?

Comment: @TheMercury79 That's just how Riemann sums work. The answer is not unique, there are multiple integrals that equal this sum, but you have a degree of freedom in choosing $a$, so I chose $a=0$. Then from letting $\Delta t = \frac{1}{n}$, we get that $b = 1$. Another way to write the integral would have been $$\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1}{t+1}\:dt$$ by letting $\Delta t = \frac{x^2}{n}$